# Muting Sounds in Android App with Shared Preferences Not Working

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I'm building my first Android app, so apologies in advance for my lack of expertise. I've been banging away at this issue for 2 days so far. When I set the sound to mute in my Settings Activity via Shared Preferences, the setting does not 'stick'. Here is the code from my Main Activity:

```
SharedPreferences settingsSP;
boolean muteSound;
```

Then in onCreate:

```
settingsSP = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PlayerPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
muteSound = settingsSP.getBoolean("muteSound", false);
```

Then I obviously use the muteSound variable to determine whether or not to play sounds within the MainActivity. Now when I go the Settings activity I have this code:

```
SharedPreferences settingsSP;
boolean muteSound;
```

Then in onCreate I have this:

```
settingsSP = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PlayerPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


if (muteSound) {
      activitySettingsBinding.displayMuteCheckBox.setChecked(true);      
} else {
      activitySettingsBinding.displayMuteCheckBox.setChecked(false);     
}


activitySettingsBinding.displayMuteCheckBox.setOnClickListener(v -> {

    if (activitySettingsBinding.displayMuteCheckBox.isChecked()) {

        muteSound = true;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settingsSP.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("muteSound", muteSound);
        editor.apply();

    } else {

        muteSound = false;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settingsSP.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("muteSound", muteSound);
        editor.apply();

        soundPool.play(bubble, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);

}
```

The xml code:

```
<CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/displayMuteCheckBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                    android:paddingTop="16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:text="Mute Sound"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:theme="@style/CheckBoxStyle" />
```

I placed a number of log.d tags throughout the code so that I observe what was happening. For example after I cold booted the app in Android Studio:

- Open MainActivity, onCreate muteSound = false
- Tap Settings button and the Settings onCreate lists muteSound = false
- I **check the checkbox** to set it to muteSounds = true
- I tap return button within Settings to return to MainActivity
- MainActivity onCreate muteSound = true
- **Tap Settings button and the Settings onCreate lists muteSound = false**
- And the checkbox is unchecked - because muteSound = false

I can't figure out why the settings is not sticking. When I checked to set the muteSound to be true, that settings is lost when I return to the Settings Activity. I've searched the code to see if I set muteSound = true on accident somewhere else, but when searching the usages I did not find any. Is my assumption about sharePreferences incorrect. It doesn't appear to hold the settings. Or perhaps am I using the checkbox incorrectly, maybe I should be using another type of button here. I would like to use checkboxes to control the display of the score, time and other items on the MainActivity and throughout other app Activities, but if I can't figure this gap in my knowledge I won't be able to. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: What does this have to do with SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **displayMuteCheckBox**, use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` instead of `setOnClickListener` and use **settingsSP** variable to store value in SharedPreferences instead of creating new object of SharedPreferences.Editor:

```
activitySettingsBinding.displayMuteCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            settingsSP.edit().putBoolean("muteSound", isChecked).apply();

            if (isChecked)
                soundPool.play(bubble, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much Zeero0! I made a few changes but with your help I was able to get it to work! I greatly appreciate your help!